# MsalClientException when I try to connect a SharePoint Online site with Runbook Designer 2019

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am trying to automate a list on my SharePoint Online site and I need to do it with the Orchestrator Runbook Designer in the System Center 2019.

When I tried to add a configuration of the website to the Runbook Designer, the way other On-Premise websites (these work fine) got added ([image: Image of Configuration Form], URL in SharePoint Site, User Name, Domain, Password, SP Online "True" instead off "False" this time obviously) in order to access the list items, I get a WebException. The detail says: Connection got closed: Unexpected error while sending.

[image: Image of WebException]

I saw on this site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/orchestrator/integration-pack-for-microsoft-sharepoint?view=sc-orch-2019) the option of "Configure the pack connections for Modern Auth (SharePoint Online)".

When I try to connect the website following this tutorial with "Authenticate via AAD using OAuth" = "True" I get an MsalClientException with the detail: User realm discovery failed.

[image: Image of MsalClientException]

I tried different users, with and without a domain but nothing helps and I can't find anything to this topic online.

I hope someone can help me.